# Seeking for references - Bowen Formula and a link between dimension theory and thermodynamic formalism

Tags: reference-request, fractals, dimension-theory, thermodynamic-formalism

I'm needing references - preferably published papers and books - about this subject. I'm relatively new to the state of the art of fractal geometry and am way too inexperienced to seek for myself at the good and legal sources.

If anyone knows a textbook that contemplates the Bowen formula, that'd be great. I found Iommi's notes, but since I already studied it, now I'm seeking something maybe on the direction of a next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's Dimension Theory in Dynamical Systems by Yakov Pesin.